# Where to implement extra business logic on authorization?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles, authorize-attribute

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application and this is my problem:

When accesing an action in controller, beside checking if logged user in in allowed role with Authorize attribute, i need to include logic conserning if user i want to edit(it's id comes as a parameter of action) has lower role than the logged user( i dont want to allow regular users to edit admins etc.)

Where should i implement this logic? I wanted to override methods in AuthorizeAttribute and simply add this logic there, but in that case i would have to send the user i want to edit in parameter of the attribute, but that is not allowed.

Another option would be to create private method in the controller, but if i want to use this logic in other controllers i would have to repeat this code again and again.

What is the right solution please?

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute( AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true )]
public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string _roles { get; set; }            
    private UserEntity _user { get; set; }
    private UserEntity _loggedUser { get; set; }

    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(string Roles, string User, int Id)
    { 
        _user = new UserEntity();
        _loggedUser = new UserEntity();
        _roles = Roles;
    }

    //Called when access is denied
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
    {                        
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary( new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" } )
        );                 
    }

    //Core authentication, called before each action
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore( HttpContextBase httpContext )
    {            
        bool b = false;
        string[] roles = _roles.Split(',');
        //Is user logged in?
        if ( httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
        { 
            //If user is logged in and we need a custom check:
            if ( roles.Any(r => httpContext.User.IsInRole(r)) && HasPermission(_user, _loggedUser))
                b = true;
        }
        //Returns true or false, meaning allow or deny. False will call HandleUnauthorizedRequest above
        return b;
    }

    private bool HasPermission(UserEntity user, UserEntity loggedUser)
    {
        if (user.IsAdmin) return false;
        if (loggedUser.IsAdmin || loggedUser.IsApplicationAdmin) return true;                                   

        if (loggedUser.IsAmbassador)
        { 
            if (user.IsApplicationAdmin)
            { return false; }
            else
            { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, at the moment im just creating empty fake objects 
     _user and 
     _loggedUser in constructor because i dont know how to pass them.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you need to create your own Authorization attribute deriving from `AuthorizeAttribute`, so that you can implement these parameters you want, and then you can override the `OnAuthorization` method to implement your specific logic:

This is the method you have to override: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization(v=vs.118).aspx

Auternatively, you can implement an `IAuthorizationFilter`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter(v=vs.118).aspx

And finally, you can register both AuthorizeAttributes and IAuthorizationFilters globally, so you don't have to place them on top of each action or controller: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters

Comment: I know i should implement these, and i already did. But i need to hand an object of user, lets say UserEntity class. I know i cannot do that, so at least i want to hand email of user which is unique for my users. When i implement my custom attributes right, can i do something like this? [CustomAttribute(Roles = "admin, administrator"), Email = Model.UserToEdit]... i am pretty sure i cannot, i can only hardcode it like Email = abc@def.com... But i dont know what the email should be at that time